# Can't figure out php insert

Tags: php, html, mysql

The first section is from my updatecompany.php page, this is looking for the passed vars to update or display.

I keep getting errors that no ID is set, I can't for the life of me figure out where i went wrong. Any help would be great!

```
if (isset($_POST["id"]) && is_numeric($_POST["id"])){
 $id = $_POST["id"];
 $vid = \Fr\LS::getCompany("id", $id);
 $vname = \Fr\LS::getCompany("name", $id);
 $vlogo = \Fr\LS::getCompany("logo", $id);
 $vinfo = \Fr\LS::getCompany("info", $id);
 $vsite = \Fr\LS::getCompany("site", $id);
 $vest = \Fr\LS::getCompany("est", $id);
}elseif ( isset($_POST["update"]) ){
  \Fr\LS::updateCompany(array(
  "name" => $_POST["name"],
  "logo" => $_POST["logo"],
  "info" => $_POST["info"],
  "site" => $_POST["site"],
  "est" => $_POST["est"]),
  $_POST["idnum"]);
echo "<center>Company updated!";
echo "<br><a href='updatecompany.php" . $_POST["idnum"] ."'>go back</a></center>";
}else {
  die("No server with that id.");
}
```

This is from my include with the function.

```
public static function updateCompany($toUpdate = array(), $company = null){
 self::construct();
 if( is_array($toUpdate) && !isset($toUpdate['id']) ){
  if($company == null){
    echo "No company ID set!";
  }
  $columns = "";
  foreach($toUpdate as $k => $v){
    $columns .= "`$k` = :$k, ";
  }

  $sql = self::$dbh->prepare("UPDATE companys SET {$columns} WHERE `id` = :id");
  $sql->bindValue(":id", $company);
  foreach($toUpdate as $key => $value){
    $value = htmlspecialchars($value);
    $sql->bindValue(":$key", $value);
  }
  $sql->execute();

}else{
  return false;
}
}
```

Here are the errors.

> 2017/01/06 16:39:19 [error] 9682#9682: *2752 FastCGI sent in stderr:
>   "PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: logo in
>   /xxx/xxx/xxxxxxxxxxx/master/updatecompany.php on line 17 PHP message:
>   PHP Notice:  Undefined index: idnum in
>   /xxx/xxx/xxxxxxxxxxx/master/updatecompany.php on line 21 PHP message:
>   PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `id` =
>   NULL' at line 1' in /xxx/xxx/xxxxxxxxxxx/inc/inc.php:917 Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 /xxx/xxx/xxxxxxxxxxx/inc/inc.php(917): PDOStatement->execute()
>
> ## 1 /xxx/xxx/xxxxxxxxxxx/master/updatecompany.php(21): Fr\LS::updateCompany(Array, NULL)
>
> ## 2 {main}   thrown in /xxx/xxx/xxxxxxxxxxx/inc/inc.php on line 917" while reading response header from upstream, client: 75.189.195.82,
>
> server: www.xxxxxxxx.com, request: "POST /master/updatecompany.php
>   HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host:
>   "www.xxxxxxxx.com", referrer:
>   "http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/master/updatecompany.php"

Here is the html form

```
<form action="updatecompany.php" method='POST'>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="ID">ID:</label>
  <input name="idnum" type="" class="form-control" id="" value="<?php echo $vid; ?>" disabled>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="Name">Name:</label>
  <input name="name" type="" class="form-control" id="name" value="<?php echo $vname; ?>">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="Logo">Logo:</label>
  <input type="" class="form-control" id="logo" value="<?php echo $vlogo; ?>">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="Info">Info:</label>
  <textarea name="info" class="form-control" rows="5" id="info"><?php echo $vinfo; ?></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="Site">Site:</label>
  <input name="site" type="" class="form-control" id="site" value="<?php echo $vsite; ?>">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="EST">EST:</label>
  <input name="est" type="" class="form-control" id="est" value="<?php echo $vest; ?>">
</div>
<button type="submit" value="update" name="update" id="update" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Any extra info needed let me know! I have be scouring the interwebs looking for something that could possibly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance it appears this

`$columns = "";
  foreach($toUpdate as $k => $v){
    $columns .= "`$k`= :$k, ";
  }`

is generating something like this

> `name` = :name, `foo` = :foo,

That trailing comma at the end would generate incorrect SQL.

Comment: I tried that, didn't do anything, I get the error "No company ID set!" In the browser when I try to update. I am thinking the isset is messing me up maybe?